# Java Aerospike Record Cutting Off TTL in Map Values

Tags: java, aerospike

I'm using the following Aerospike Client Version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aerospike</groupId>
    <artifactId>aerospike-client</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

And I had an Aerospike client set up and tried to retrieve one record which is a mapping between ID and token, like the following:

```
{<bin_name> = map{"<some_id>"="<some_token>::<token_ttl>"}}
```

The record I get is like the following (by `Record.toString()`, [doc link](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/)):

```
(gen:1),(exp:263680981),(bins:(<bin_name>:{"<some_id>"="<some_token>::<token_ttl>"}))
```

However, I get the following when I tried to retrieve the bin directly (by either `Record.getMap` or `Record.getValue`):

```
{"<some_id>"="<some_token>"}
```

Have anyone seen this auto filter TTL behavior before?

Any idea on how to not filter the TTL part? Thanks.

Comment: Can you attach Java code that reproduces this? I have no idea what `"<some_token>::<token_ttl>"` stands for. If that's a string, it's unlikely Aerospike is truncating it.  Look at the definition for [MapOperation](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/cdt/MapOperation.html) and the [example code](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-java/blob/master/examples/src/com/aerospike/examples/ListMap.java) for map and list.

Comment: It's string. The bin key is a String, the bin value is a Map<String, String>, where the Map.value is a String in a format of "<token>::<token_ttl>". And yes I found it weird as well and currently still can't find the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the issue ...

Looks like the [com.aerospike.client.Record](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/Record.html#getMap(java.lang.String)) 's function "getMap" (or any other get function) is returning the reference of to the instance variable, and I was modifying it's value and putting it back into the same reference ...

I guess it is my bad for not making a copy of it when assigning it to variables, or should the `Record` class really return a copy of its variables?

Comment: No, that does not sound right. Data on the Aerospike server will not get modified by what you do to the returned value in the client. The only time data gets updated on the database is when you send it back with a put call (ie specifically you write it back) to the database.

Comment: Maybe I explained it wrong. The data on AS did not get modified. The actual java record object got modified.
Let me start over...I created a AS client in java, and retrieved a Record object from that client. The Record has its own instance variables, such as the "bins". When I try to get some bin value from the Record class methods "getMap", it returns a reference instead of a copy to the Record's instance variable. So I ended up modifying the Record's variable when updating the returned reference from "getMap".